# What other diseases can be alleviated by warm climates?

Tags: environmental-climate

[Dignity Health](https://www.dignityhealth.org/articles/weather-and-health-how-warm-dry-climates-can-help) lists Rheumatoid Arthritis, Crohn's Disease, and Heart Disease. But what other diseases can be lessened by moving to a warmer climate?   The following articles don't stipulate the diseases.

[Harrison Moore - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrison_Moore)

> but his poor health forced him to move to Australia, seeking a better climate.

[The Health Benefits of a Warmer Climate](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Emoore/HealthBenefitsofWarmer.html) by [Thomas Gale Moore](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Emoore/Bio.html).

> **Simply put, warmer weather means fewer deaths.**
>
> [. . .]
>
> The prestigious *International Journal of Biometeorology* published further confirmation of the beneficial consequences of heat earlier this year (WCR Vol. 4 No. 9). That research of Alexander Lerchl of Münster, Germany’ Institute of Reproductive Medicine, shows that **colder weather, rather than hotter, is a more significant killer**. Lerchl culled information from German mortality statistics gathered between 1946 and 1995, relating them to corresponding air temperatures.

> Not only is mortality higher in the winter but a very cold winter produces a higher number of deaths. During the summer, according to Lerchl’s analysis, heat spells do lead to more deaths; but the increase is relatively small compared to deaths from the cold.

> [. . .]

> Although heat waves in Britain kill people, cold weather fells more.

> [. . .]

> As Bentham puts it, temperatures in England and Wales are sub-optimal for human health. Since humans evolved in Africa in a much warmer climate, it is unsurprising that the cold weather of the northern portions of the globe is less than beneficial for most.

Comment: This is a list question, which means every answer is potentially as correct as any other, there is no single right answer, and it's impossible to know when (or if) the list is complete. These are the reasons why list questions aren't a good fit for the SE model and aren't considered on topic. Please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139618/are-list-questions-off-topic) meta topic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a list question.